# Dynamic form element not being recognized in $_post

Tags: php, html

I have a function that dynamically generates a form. Everything worked perfectly until I needed to add in an additional field to grab the unix timestamp that is to be passed in.

The new hiddden field is identical to the previous one, except for the name of course, but `task_date` is NEVER included in the posted values.

Here is the function

```
  private function addTaskForm($court_id, $judge_id, $employee_id, $date)
  {
   // display add task form

      // if judge_id == null then display judge selection box
      // if employee_id == null then display employee selection box
   $form = "<form method='post' action='#'>";
   $form .= "<input type='hidden' name='court_id' value='$court_id'>";
   $form .= "<input type='hidden' name='task_date' value='$date'>";     <= this is the NEW element
    if($judge_id == null)
        $form .= Utils::selectJudge($this->db)."<br />";
    else
        $form .="<input type='hidden' name='judge_id' value='$judge_id'>";
    if($employee_id == null)
      $form .= Utils::selectEmployee($this->db)."<br />";
    else
        $form .="<input type='hidden' name='employee_id' value='$employee_id'>";                 

    $form .=Utils::selectTask($this->db)."<br /><br />
     <select name='start_time'><option>Start</option>".Utils::selectTime()." </select> - 
     <select name='end_time'><option>End</option>".Utils::selectTime()." </select>
    <input type='submit' name='btnAddTask' value='Add Task'>
</form>";

   return $form;
```

}

Here is the output after cycling through the posted values:

```
key: court_id: 3
key: judge_id: 1
key: employee_id: 217
key: task_id: 1
key: start_time: 0800
key: end_time: Uknown
key: btnAddTask: Add Task
```

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($date)`? And `var_dump($_POST['task_date'])`

Comment: It's likely `$date` is not set, and as you POST the form the field is submitted empty. In your cycling are you by any chance skipping empty elements in the input array?

Comment: no, the date is set to the correct value...I did var_dump on $date and the value is correct...the var_dump for $_POST['task_date'] turned out to be null, but that's expected because its not in the post values

Comment: are either `$judge_id` or `$employee_id` being set as null when calling the function?  `echo addTaskForm($court_id, $date)`?

Comment: both of them could be until they are selected from within this form

Comment: but are you doing `echo addTaskForm($court_id, null, null, $date);` OR `echo addTaskForm($court_id, $date);`? if the later, try changing the order of the parameters - `function addTaskForm($court_id, $date, $judge_id, $employee_id){...`

Comment: Also, Before submitting the form, have you viewed the html source code to make sure that the input value `<input type='hidden' name='task_date' value=''>` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try These

> - Restart The Server Services
> - Change `$form = "<form method='post' action='#?nocache=". rand() ."'>";`
> - Check if Browser is offline
> - Clear the Caches (or try the above code)
> - Remember to Check whether you are seeking the correct php file :-)

**update**

can you add this  call and send back the result

```
if(isset($_POST['task_date']))
echo ($_POST['task_date']);
```

`echo addTaskForm("something","something","something","this thing can be wrong");`

i tried , it works fine . 
if error continues you have options of changing `task_date` to something

Comment: none of those worked, and I know its the correct php file because the rest of the form elements are present in the posted values

Comment: can you change the name='task_date' to something?

Comment: Figured it out......STUPID mistake, I kept hitting refresh instead of trying the submit the form after making changes to the date parameter.....thanks for the help everyone!